# define variable with a structure member

Tags: c, arrays, structure

I'm a beginner, taking a class.  Knowledge level = very minimal.

> Error is expedected identifier or '(' at the l of list[0] (and list[1] etc..

```
void hardcode(count, &list[SIZE]) 
{
    struct family list1 = { "test", "case", 'F', '1', '1', '1', 2500, 2000 };
    list[0] = list1;
    struct family list2 = { "test2", "case2",'M', '4', '4', '2', 5000,1970 };
    list[1] = list2; 
}
```

I have declared the structure in my `main()`.. `struct test list[SIZE]`, then called this function passing it a counter, and the structure.

Comment: please show the typedef for list.

Comment: @Mike: `list` is not a type, and the syntax error the compiler complains about comes at the `&`, before `list`.

Comment: Technically, there is no question in your question. I deduce you are asking about the error message a compiler generates for the line `void hardcode(count, &list[SIZE])`, but you should be clearer about asking a specific question.

Comment: @Horyd you should add types to arguments there (at least): `void hardcode(count, &list[SIZE]) `

Comment: What is `&list[SIZE]` supposed to mean? Should this be `struct family *list[SIZE]`?

Answer (score 1):

`void hardcode(count, &list[SIZE])` is not a valid declaration in C for two reasons:

- You must specify the types of the parameters, such as `void hardcode(int count, struct test list[SIZE])`. (Notice the insertion of `int` for `count` and `struct test` for `list`.)
- C does not have built-in references; you cannot use `&` to describe the type of a a parameter. When you are passing an array, it will automatically be converted to a pointer to its first element, and that serves as a reference to the array. So you can simply declare the function as above. (Although `struct test list[SIZE]` declares an array, when it is a function parameter, it is automatically adjusted to have the type of a pointer to an element of the array. So passing an array argument actually passes a pointer, and receiving an array parameter actually receives a pointer.)

Comment: Still confused...  my code:  'typedef test { char fname[20]; char lname[20] } list[SIZE];'   prototype delaration 'void hardcode (int count, struct test list[SIZE]; changed my function call to 'void hardcode (int counter, struct test list[SIZE]);' still generates same error..

Comment: @Horyd: Do not put types in the function call. Types go in the declaration; they are declaring what types the function takes. In the actual call, you supply values, not types.

Comment: ok so the prototype is</br>void hardcode (int counter, struct test list[SIZE]);     </br>then the fuction and the function call is </br>void hardcode(count, list[SIZE])

Comment: @Horyd: No, the function call would be `hardcode(count, list)`. You do not put the `void` before the function when calling it; that is for a declaration. Similarly, `[SIZE]` is used in a declaration to specify the size of an array. In an expression, it does not specify the size; it indexes the array to get a single element. You do not want a single element; you want the entire array (which will be converted to a pointer to its first element for the call).

Comment: Thanks for your help so far!  I think im getting closer.  now getting a "conflicting type for 'hardcode'...     The prototype is: void hardcode (int count, struct test list[]);  my new function is: void hardcode(count, list), and the call is hardcode(count, list)...

Comment: Im getting another error, that i think is linked to the conflicting error I mention above... Not only am I getting a conflicting type for the function, but I'm getting a subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or vector when I use the array in the function.. for example: printf("last name: %s\n", list[i].fname);